# If $|X|<|Y|$ then $|Y|=|Y-X|$ (with $Y$ infinite)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals, axiom-of-choice

Like the title says, I would like to prove that if $|X|<|Y|$ then $|Y|=|Y-X|$. (with $Y$ infinite)

I know I have to use the axiom of choice, but I've no idea about how to proceed.

Any help is welcome :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the axiom of choice, one can show that $|X|+|Y|=\max\{|X|,|Y|\}$. This suffices in order to prove that $|Y|=|Y-X|$ using the following [trivial] claim: $|Y|=|Y\setminus X|+|X|$.

It is necessary to use the axiom of choice, and in fact this is *equivalent* to the axiom of choice. If the axiom of choice fails then there is some $X$ which cannot be well-ordered and $A$ which can be well-ordered such that $|A|\nleq|X|$. Take $Y=A\cup X$ (and assume this is a disjoint union).

Then $|X|<|Y|$, since $|A|\leq|Y|$ but $|A|\nleq|X|$; and at the same time $|Y-X|<|Y|$, since $|Y-X|=|A|$, which is well-orderable, whereas $|Y|$ itself is not well-orderable.

Comment: You're tacitly using Cantor--Bernstein.  Maybe that should be mentioned.

Comment: You're right. I mentioned that explicitly to the OP's previous question, though, so I felt it a bit unnecessary here.

Comment: With $|Y|=|Y|+|Y|$ do you mean that given $K$ and $Y$ such that $|K|=|Y|$ then $|Y|=|K|=|Y \cup K|$ ?

Comment: @Benzio: I mean that there is a bijection between $Y$ and $Y\times\{0,1\}$.

Comment: How does this series of inequalities (which became a series of equalities) help us?

Comment: If $|Y|=|Y|+|Y|$ means that there is a bijection between $Y$ and $Y \times \{0,1\}$ what meaning do you give to $|Y-X|+|Y|$? sorry I never seen this notation for infinite cardinalities

Comment: Ok maybe I get it intuitively: are elements either of $Y-X$ or of $Y$

Comment: @Benzio: Perhaps it is advisable that you read a little bit about cardinal arithmetic first. These things (e.g. what is $|Y|+|Y|$ or $|Y\setminus X|+|Y|$) are pretty much the first definition given in any reasonable text which includes a chapter about cardinal arithmetic. If you struggle to understand that, it is advisable to strengthen your basis, before extending the height of the pyramid.

Comment: @Belgi: What do you mean by that?

Comment: I didn't understand how to deduce the desired equality. From what I understand showing that the sum of two infinite cardinals equals to one of them only gives us an inequality between them (I'm sorry that I am not writing exactly what I meant with tex, I'm using a mobile phone)

Comment: @Belgi: Thanks!